# why accessing a method specific to an object from a super reference fails?

Tags: java

Consider, for example, the following code

```
class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Parent obj = new Child();

    obj.firstMethod(); // Prints >> from child Class (polymorphism, great!)
    obj.secondMethod(); // why this call fails? 
                        // the obj variable reference a Child object 
                        // which has secondMethod!

  }

  static class Parent {

    Parent() {}

    void firstMethod () {
      System.out.println("from Parent Class");
    }
  }

  static class Child extends Parent {

    Child() {}

    @Override
    void firstMethod () {
      System.out.println("from child Class");
    }

    void secondMethod () {
      //
    }
  }
}
```

So obj variable is just a reference of type Parent, and the actual object the reference is pointing to is of type Child. I can't understand why such access fails!

Comment: In simple: the static type (Parent in this case) of the object tells which functions you can call. The dynamic (Child) how they will be executed. Since Parent does no have a secondMethod, and the compiler only knows about the static type at compile time, it will fail to compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language spec answer: refer to [JLS Sec 15.12](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12). Emphasis added.

> **15.12.1. Compile-Time Step 1: Determine Class or Interface to Search**
>
> The first step in processing a method invocation at compile time is to figure out the name of the method to be invoked and **which class or interface to search for definitions of methods of that name**.
>
> ...
>
> For the class or interface to search, there are six cases to consider, depending on the form that precedes the left parenthesis of the MethodInvocation:
>
> - ...
> - If the form is *ExpressionName . [TypeArguments] Identifier*, then the class or interface to search is the **declared type `T` of the variable denoted by ExpressionName** if `T` is a class or interface type, or the upper bound of `T` if `T` is a type variable.
>
> **15.12.2. Compile-Time Step 2: Determine Method Signature**
>
> The second step **searches the type determined in the previous step** for member methods.

In `obj.secondMethod();`, `ExpressionName` is `obj`, which has declared type `Parent`. As such, the declared type `T` is `Parent`, not `Child`, so only methods in `Parent` are searched for. There's no method in `Parent` called `secondMethod`, so it's a compile-time error.

Answer (score 4):

Because the declared type `Parent` doesn't contain the method : `void secondMethod ()`.
So, the compilation fails.
The polymorphism works only if both classes (Parent and Child) have a common method which comes from the parent class and that the child class overrides as in your firstMethod() example.
 
In your case, you call a method specific to the child class, so you should declare 
`Child obj = new Child()` or do a cast to `Child` when you call `secondMethod()`.

Don't forget that Polymorphism allows variables to have a dynamic behavior by using at runtime the implementation of the effective instance behind the variable. It is therefore meaningful only if the classes share a same operation.